# HtmlAgilityPack XPath Invalid Token

Tags: windows-phone-7, xpath, html-agility-pack

Seeing an invalid token exception occassionally. The exception isn't thrown every time and the XPath is static. Not sure what is going on.

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@itemprop,'softwareVersion')]");
```

.

```
Message:

'//*[contains(@itemprop,'softwareVersion')]' has an invalid token.


StackTrace:

at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.CheckToken(LexKind t)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParsePredicate(AstNode qyInput)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseStep(AstNode qyInput)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseRelativeLocationPath(AstNode qyInput)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseLocationPath(AstNode qyInput)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParsePathExpr(AstNode qyInput)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseUnionExpr(AstNode qyInput)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseUnaryExpr(AstNode qyInput)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseMultiplicativeExpr(AstNode qyInput)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseAdditiveExpr(AstNode qyInput)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseRelationalExpr(AstNode qyInput)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseEqualityExpr(AstNode qyInput)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseAndExpr(AstNode qyInput)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseOrExpr(AstNode qyInput)
at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseXPathExpresion(String xpathExpresion)
at System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression.Compile(String xpath, IXmlNamespaceResolver nsResolver)
at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select(String xpath)
at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.SelectSingleNode(String xpath)
```

I also see it sometimes for this, with the same invalid token exception

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'item')]");
```

Comment: Is there any way to bump a question so it can get more views?

Comment: You can start a bounty but i guess that you might need more reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the "*" :

`doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//[contains(@itemprop,'softwareVersion')]");`